# Is there a way to pull the index of a Python list of booleans of where short circuiting occurs?

Tags: python-3.x, list, boolean, any, short-circuiting

My main focus has been on `any` and `all` function of Python 3.7. Sometimes, I would like to figure out where the short-circuit occurs in a list of booleans

i.e.

```
any([False, False, True, False, True, True])
```

would return 2.

What is a way to do so without using a loop?

Edit: I realized that this is a first occurrence problem. Which, already has many solutions out there :p

Comment: Even `any` uses a loop. There's no way to avoid it, though you can short circuit. Maybe you're looking for `next(i for i, val in enumerate(mylist) if not val)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), which accepts a function and an iterable. Each element of the iterable is passed into the function and taken until the first `False`.

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> lst = [False, False, True, False, True, True]
>>> len(list(takewhile(lambda x: not x, lst)))
2
```

Another option from the comments is

```
next(i for i, val in enumerate(mylist) if val)
```

which makes an iterator of indices of truthy values in `mylist` and forwards it one step to the first truthy value index, which is also short-circuiting and space-efficient.

`any` [does short circuit](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b104ecbbafc14f9ca0c8371963c45dca893f6b75/Python/bltinmodule.c#L377) although it doesn't produce an index.